# Can I clear Facebook Analytics before the iOS app goes live?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, analytics, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I recently started using Facebook analytics for the iOS apps I create. However, the FB analytics collects a lot of data during the testing periods of my app that I do not want to be included in analytics. Is there any option to clear out all of the stats FB analytics has collected so I can clear out test data before the app goes live in the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to do this. You could just ignore the data prior to date X (before your public release) and you should be OK.